# Re-Select features from dataset giving other result

Tags: r, selection

Could anyone please help me with this?

I am trying to select/split some features from the dataset, before I was able to do it with this:

My data had 50 features and here I reduce to 24.

```
trainQ1 <- df_2015_Q1[,1:24]
#trainQ1       12312312 obs. of 24 variables
```

But now I use the same code

```
age <- trainQ1[,1:4]
#and returns
#age                 int [1:4] 1 2 3 4
```

What going on here??

Comment: can you share part of your dataset? maybe do `dput(head(trainQ1))` for an example, then it might be easier to see what's going on

Comment: That is weird! Check the classes of those objects with `class( object )`